# PHP driver for Cassandra 2.2.5

Tags: php, cassandra, driver

I am trying to connect php with cassandra and can't even get past first step.

I am using datastax php driver and following the steps in the [github](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md)

I am using cassandra 2.2.5 and php 5.5.9 and ubuntu 14.04LTS.
It seems datastax php driver supports only till cassandra 2.1

Is there any driver for cassandra 2.2.* ??

This is what I am trying to do

```
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()          
                ->build();
```

And its throwing

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cassandra' not found

Comment: I think you have installation error. Just look at `phpinfo()` to chek whether `cassandra.so` is loaded or not

Comment: @Undefined_variable When I use 
php -d="extension=modules/cassandra.so" -m
anywhere except the php-cassandra driver file it doesn't show cassandra 
though if I execute the same command inside php-cassandra folder it shows cassandra